# JavaScript send data from input field to ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have following Code. But the String in the Database is empty. Why does it not work to get the string from the input field?

HTML

```
 <div id="todo">
   <h2>Todo Liste</h2> 
   <form method="get">
     <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="name" required>
     <input type="text"  class="inputField" name="inputData" id="myInput" placeholder="title"  required><br><br>
     <span onclick="newElement(); sendData(this.value)" class="addBtn">Add</span><br><br>
    </form>
```

JavaScript

```
function sendData(str) {
  const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "saveData.php?q=" + str);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

To get the Value on the html page:

```
<p>Response from PHP <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
```

to bring the data in the html

```
function newElement() {
var li = document.createElement("li");
var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    li.appendChild(t);
  
      document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
    
  }
```

and i want to get the data of the text, a user typed in. this is where i fail.

My idea was

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("inputField"));
```

How can I get the element?

Comment: Well we don't know what code you use to save to the database. But if the real problem is that it isn't even sending te data in the XHR request, the it's most likely because `this.value` refers to the value of the `span`, not he value of either of the input fields.

Comment: okay. I will edit the post. Do you know how to get the value from the input field?

Comment: my idea was to make document.getELementById('myInput'), but it does not work?

Comment: Probably, you have an issue with the code `</div>` missing. Please check if this is the error.

Comment: no this was not the error. is this.value right?

Comment: or how to call the function with the parameter

Comment: i don´t get the value with   var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value; console.log(inputValue);

Comment: That looks right, but edit the question please to show in context how you used it.

Comment: i updated my post

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks. You need to get the value during the sendData function and use it in your URL (in place of `str`) if you want to send it to the database.

Comment: yes i called it with sendData(document.getElementsByClassName("inputField")); ??? but this is the problem where it does not work?

Comment: Not sure why you used that, it should be `document.getElementById("myInput").value` as you already showed. And you need to use that instead of `str` within the `xmlhttp.open` command.

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("GET", "saveData.php?q=" + document.getElementById("myInput").value);`